# Add test users to Azure Active Directory

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

In Azure Active Directory, I need to add 500k test users. Is there a powershell command that I could use in order to add n number of users into Azure Active Directory. Please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to [this blog](https://charbelnemnom.com/how-to-create-bulk-users-in-azure-active-directory-with-powershell-azuread-powershell-aad/).

You can prepare users information to be created in a CSV file and then use `Import-csv` to import them.

And then use [New-AzureADUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/new-azureaduser?view=azureadps-2.0) command to create users.

Sample logic:

```
foreach($user in import-csv "C:\userinfo.csv") 
{ 
    New-AzureADUser -DisplayName $user.DisplayName ... and so on..
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Please note (see [Azure AD service limits and restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/directory-service-limits-restrictions)):

> A maximum of 50,000 Azure AD resources can be created in a single
> tenant by users of the Free edition of Azure Active Directory by
> default. If you have at least one verified domain, the default Azure
> AD service quota for your organization is extended to 300,000 Azure AD
> resources. Azure AD service quota for organizations created by
> self-service sign-up remains 50,000 Azure AD resources even after you
> performed an internal admin takeover and the organization is converted
> to a managed tenant with at least one verified domain. This service
> limit is unrelated to the pricing tier limit of 500,000 resources on
> the Azure AD pricing page. To go beyond the default quota, you must
> contact Microsoft Support.

So I'm afraid that you can't create 500K users in a tenant.

Comment: Thank you! Could you please provide a sample csv file with the required fields? Thank you!

Comment: @user989988 You can download a sample csv file here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/users-bulk-add#to-create-users-in-bulk